# Is there a method in FeynCalc for collecting like powers of four vectors?

Tags: feyncalc

If I have a polynomial in some momentum $l^{\mu}$ such as

$(q_1+l)^{\mu_1}(q_2+l)^{\mu_2}(q_3+l)^{\mu_3}...(q_n+l)^{\mu_n}$

in the numerator of an integral with measure $d^Dl$, is it possible to collect all like powers of $l$? This would be useful in order to split the integral into $n+1$ integrals - one for each power of $l$.

For example, if the numerator is

$(q_1+l)^{\mu}(q_2+l)^{\nu}l^{\rho}$,

I'd like to decompose the product into the form

$q_1^{\mu}q_2^{\nu}l^{\rho}+(g_{\sigma}^{\nu}q_1^{\mu}+g_{\sigma}^{\mu}q_2^{\nu})l^{\sigma}l^{\rho}+l^{\mu}l^{\nu}l^{\rho}$,

since the parenthetical term contains the Lorentz structure of the only even term in the numerator.  It should be noted that the specific integrals which I am computing cannot be simplified using Passarino-Veltman reduction.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: More a comment than an answer (my reputation doesn't allow me to comment): Funny that you ask, I encountered exactly the same problem today.
My trick is a rather primitive workaround: I simply define a certain four vector K to be orthogonal to everything except for the vector in which I want to expand, after which I use Contract[].

Comment: Ask here: https://feyncalc.github.io/forum

Comment: Check out http://www.feyncalc.org/FeynCalcBook/TIDL/

Comment: how about DiracSimplify or Calc?